# How to assign returned url with angular and firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage

Im attempting to get a group of image urls returned from firebase then iterate through my array and assign them. I'm not sure how to do it.  I can not use this.liquors[i] because it returns as undefined since the this key word points to a different scope.

code below

Thank you!

```
this.liquorService.getList().subscribe(liquors => {

  this.liquors = liquors;

  for(var i = 0; i < this.liquors.length; i++){

  //get Image from storage
  let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
  let spaceRef = storageRef.child(this.liquors[i].path)
  storageRef.child(this.liquors[i].path).getDownloadURL().then((url) => {


    //NOT SURE WHAT TO DO HERE!!

  }).catch((error) => {

    console.log(error);

  })


 }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `subscribe` you're returned a `DataSnapshot`. You can iterate through this snapshot with `forEach`. You can read more about it at the [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#forEach).

```
  this.liquorService.getList().subscribe(liquors => {
    this.liquores = liquores;

    this.liquors.forEach(snapshot => {
      let liquor = snapshot.val();
      let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
      let spaceRef = storageRef.child(liquor.path);

      storageRef.child(liquor.path).getDownloadURL()
        .then((url) => {
          // Do some logic
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    });
  });
```

Comment: No problems. Can you accept this as the answer please :)